# Joomla , forms with upload and custom field from inside the administration panel

Tags: forms, joomla, upload, administration

I want a plugin for joomla like jforms or chronoforms in order to make a form to upload videos along with other custom fields to db and manage them. The only problem is I want this functionality to be made from inside the administrator console and not to appear on a page at my site's frontend. My site does not have a login service , so I need to make the admin able to login to administration panel and from there to upload and manage videos. 
Do you know of a plugin wich supports this functionality? Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/multimedia-channels/video-channels/5659?qh=YToxMjp7aTowO3M6NToibWVkaWEiO2k6MTtzOjc6Im1lZGlhJ3MiO2k6MjtzOjY6Im1lZGlhcyI7aTozO3M6NjoiJ21lZGlhIjtpOjQ7czo2OiJ1cGxvYWQiO2k6NTtzOjg6InVwbG9hZGVkIjtpOjY7czo3OiJ1cGxvYWRzIjtpOjc7czo5OiJ1cGxvYWRpbmciO2k6ODtzOjg6InVwbG9hZGVyIjtpOjk7czo5OiJ1cGxvYWRlcnMiO2k6MTA7czo3OiIndXBsb2FkIjtpOjExO3M6MTI6Im1lZGlhIHVwbG9hZCI7fQ%3D%3D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct plugin. It is fabrik. http://fabrikar.com